# How to get individual users data after login in django?

Tags: django, authentication

iam new to django.Can anyone send me the code of signup and login page to get particular details of the username without using django.contrib.auth.models import User.
(i.e if we login with some usename then it should only give details of that username not remaining).

Answer (score 0):

Find view you want manipulate user in, declare user like `current_user = request.user`. I will provide you my login and register views below. In examples shown below I had `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`, but you can modify it as shown above.

Register:

```py
def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('todoapp:home')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            if form.is_valid():
                if check_does_email_already_exist(email):
                    form.save()
                    messages.success(request, "User is registered sucessfully")
                    return redirect('todoapp:login')
                else:
                    messages.warning(
                        request, "User with same email already exist")
            else:
                messages.warning(
                    request, "That username already exist or your password is too short")
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

Login:

```py
def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('todoapp:home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('uname')
            password = request.POST.get('passwd')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('todoapp:home')
            else:
                messages.warning(
                    request, "Your password or username isn't valid")
                return redirect('todoapp:login')
        else:
            pass

        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

These are my imports:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import CreateUserForm
```

And this is my forms.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import fields


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        ]
```

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: Cant we do without importing User